# Pyplot - Visualize histogram of a list

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

Given a simple list of negative values: `l = [0, -1, -1, -1, -10, -100]`

What's the fastest way to visualize its histogram with the standard method `plt.hist(l)` ?

I want to be able to see *all* entries in the list and their relative frequencies.

Doing:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
l = [0, -1, -1, -1, -10, -100]
plt.hist(l)
plt.show()
```

Results in:

[image]

What would be the correct way to set the number of the bins in the current case?

Any help highly apprecited

Comment: Using the `bins` argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose all the entries in your list `l` are integers. You can use [`bins`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) to control the number or size of bins in your histogram.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
l = [0, -1, -1, -1, -10, -100]
plt.hist(l, bins=max(l)-min(l)+1)
ax = plt.subplot()
ax.set_xticks(l)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Could you specify how to have all the entries values plotted on the x-axis? Instead of -100, -80, -60, -40, -20, 0 only

Comment: @Employee You can use `set_xticks()` to specify the values on x-axis tick. I have changed the plot.